# "No module named simple" login_required depreciated

Tags: python, django

I wonder if there is a handy solution to achive a login required in urls like in older versions of django (using now 1.5 c1).

I thought about the django braces mixin but as far as i can see this is for class inheritage only. Or is there a way to integrate it into urls...(even if this is not a good design pattern)

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template #fails

(r'^dashboard/$', login_required(direct_to_template), {'template': 'dashboard.html'}),
```

Returns error:

> No module named simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function-based generic views were removed in 1.5 ([they were deprecated in 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views/)).

So that "simple" module doesn't exist anymore.

You want to do:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^dashboard/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="dashboard.html"))),
)
```